# Celery: How to schedule worker processes/children restart

Tags: celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I try to figure out how to setup my "celery workers" to restart after a living day.

Indeed, I configured my worker children/processes to restart after executing a task.
But in some cases, there are no tasks to execute in 3-4 days. So I need to restart the long-living children.

Do you how to do this ?

This is my actual *celery app* setup:

```
app = Celery(
    "celery",
    broker=f"amqp://bla@blabla/blablabla",
    backend="rpc://",
)

app.conf.task_serializer = "pickle"
app.conf.result_serializer = "pickle"
app.conf.accept_content = ["pickle", "application/json"]
app.conf.broker_connection_max_retries = 5
app.conf.broker_pool_limit = 1
app.conf.worker_max_tasks_per_child = 1 # Ensure 1 task is executed before restarting child
app.conf.worker_max_living_time_before_restart = 60 * 60 * 24 # The conf I want
```

Thank you :)

Comment: worker_max_tasks_per_child is something you may want to have only if you have a memory leak in your task(s)...

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's why I use it.

Comment: Celery does not have this out-of-box as far as I know. Simple workaround: restart the worker. More complicated workaround: implement remote command that basically calls the same code that is executed by when max_tasks_per_child is in use. I am sure it is not difficult to find. Maybe it is even reusable (a function that you can call). Even more complicated: implement the Celery configuration you explained above.